# Spatie Laravel Permission assign a role did not work

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Laravel 8 with Jetstream. My site has users. These users are related to many institutions, so here they have different roles inside the site, So  I made a seeder where I create the Roles and the User and the institutions; everything is fine. I use the directives `@can` in the blade view to show and hide information to different roles. Still, here it does not show anything. Despite the fact I am with an administrator, it does not show what it is supposed to show.

**Model**

```
class UserInstitutions extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasRoles;

    protected $primaryKey  = 'user_id';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $guard_name = 'web';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function institution() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Institution::class,'institution_id_f');
    }
}
```

**Seeder**

```
class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $admin = Role::create(['name' => 'Administrador']);
        $titular = Role::create(['name' => 'Titular']);
        $coor = Role::create(['name' => 'Coordinador']);
        $subcoor = Role::create(['name' => 'SubCoordinador']);
        $int = Role::create(['name' => 'Integrante']);

        Permission::create(['name' => 'home.dashboard']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'dashboard']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'institution.index']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'institution.create']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'institution.update']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'institution.delete']);

        $admin->syncPermissions(Permission::all());
        $coor->givePermissionTo('institution.index');
        $coor->givePermissionTo('institution.create');
    }
}
```

The seeder where I assign the role

```
class UserInstitutionSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $institution = Institution::all()->random();
        $user = User::all()->random();

        UserInstitutions::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'institution_id_f' => $institution->id,
            'institution_id' => $institution->institution_id,
            'email' => 'pcoordinador@gob.sv',
            'landline_phone_number' => '74859632',
            'start_date' => now(),
            'active' => 'S',
        ])->assignRole('Administrador');

        UserInstitutions::factory(5)->create();
    }
}
```

And if I check the data in the table, the role is being assigned
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOWih.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a cache issue, you can add this line at your seeder class within the run() method

```
app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();
```

If you already have a session for that user, you can clear the cache from the command line:

```
php artisan permission:cache-reset
```

Or

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/artisan#content-resetting-the-cache